# How is HORNSAT equivalent to 2SAT?

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

I raise this question because I read [Tim](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15382/tim)'s question ["Why are Hornsat, 3sat and 2sat not equivalent?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66630).

Quoting him:

"... This new problem though is polynomial time equivalent to a certain instance of 2SAT(satisfiable iff the HORNSAT is). ..."

How can I build the "certain instance of 2SAT"?

Can anybody give me pointers to papers that help writing the polynomial reduction from HORNSAT to 2SAT?

Answer (score 4):

A little bit of research in wikipedia revealed this.

- HORNSAT is $P$-complete (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability).
- 2SAT is $NL$-complete (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability).
- It is known that $NL \subseteq P$, but unknown if $NL = P$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_%28complexity%29).

Thus 2SAT is reducible to HORNSAT and HORNSAT is reducible to 2SAT if and only if $NL=P$. Hence the existence of such a reducibility is an open question.

Comment: So, I think I have misunderstood the meaning of the word "equivalence" that occurs in the quote of my question. After your answer, I think I can correctly interpret the meaning of the final posts between Tim and Stefan, relative to ["Why are Hornsat, 3sat and 2sat not equivalent?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66630/why-are-hornsat-3sat-and-2sat-not-equivalent). Many thanks. Luca

Comment: @rover There was the issue of producing a reduction which preserves witnesses. There is a trivial reduction, but it doesn't preserve witnesses so it isn't useful for solving hornsat. I would also like to point out that NL=(!=)P doesn't concern polynomial time reductions since we wouldn't gain anything by that. 2SAT is linear time solvable, so we need an at most logspace reduction for it to mean anything useful.